# Elasticsearch range query ( PHP Client )

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have this search query :

```
 $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'size' => $size,
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        "match_all" => [],
        'filter' => [
          'range' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'gte' => '2016-01-30 01:00:00',
              'lte' => '2016-01-30 08:00:00'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      'mappings' => [
        '_default_' => [
          'properties' => [
            'Tijdsperiode' => [
              'type' => 'date',
              'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```

But i can't get it to filter results between the 2 dates?

Any ideas how to fix this? DO i need to change the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to remove the `mappings` section from your search query as it doesn't belong there (i.e. it is only needed when creating your index, not when searching). Then you're probably missing a `filtered` query and that should be enough to get you some docs.

```
 $params = [
    'index' => 'veenendaal2',
    'type' => 'passanten2',
    'size' => $size,
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
          'filter' => [
            'range' => [
              'Tijdsperiode' => [
                'gte' => '2016-01-30 01:00:00',
                'lte' => '2016-01-30 08:00:00'
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ];
```